# How to install Dockerfile from GitLab to allow pull and commit

Tags: docker, commit, gitlab, pull

Is there a way to clone a Dockerfile from GitLab with the `docker` command?

I want to use the feature that allow pull and commit.

I am not sure if I have understand well but these pull and commit update the Dockerfile from the git repositories ? Or is it only locally in the next images ?

If not, is there a way to get all the change you made from the previous image made by the Dockerfile into another Dockerfile ?

I know you can clone with Git directly, but like for npm, you can also use Git url like git+https:// or git+ssh://

Answer (score 0):

The `pull`/`commit` commands affect the related image and operate directly against your configured registry, which is the official [Docker Hub Registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com/) unless configured otherwise. Perhaps some confusion may arise from the registry's support for [Automated Builds](http://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/), where the registry is directly bound to a repository and rebuilds the image every time the targeted repository branch changes.

If you wish to reuse someone's Docker image, the best approach is to simply reference it via the `FROM` instruction in your Dockerfile and effectively fork the image. While it's certainly possible to clone the original source repository and continue editing the Dockerfile contained therein, you usually **do not** want to go down that path.

So if there exists such a `foo/bar` image you want to continue building upon, the best, most direct approach to do so is to create your own Dockerfile, inherit the image by setting it as a base for your succeeding instructions via `FROM foo/bar` and possibly pushing your `baz/bar` image back into the registry if you want it to be publicly available for others to re-base upon.

Comment: I have confusion of course, thanks for the link. You didn't answer the main part of my question, is it possible to use a registry  not hosted by github ? instead of doing docker run foo/bar, where foo is the user and bar the project hosted by github, I would like to do the same with a project hoster on our private gitlab.

Comment: Yes, of course you can! The registry itself is open sourced and available at https://github.com/docker/docker-registry and your local `docker` client will have full support and seamlessly interact with it. The only notable feature lacking in private registries is support for automated builds, as this is a special feature Docker provides on top of it's own infrastructure.